# Where to place FluentValidation validator class in a two project solution

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have a web project and a class library project in one solution. The class library project contains the models for all non-identity data. I have created a validator class to validate uniqueness in a table (Category). When I place the validator class into the class library project, it cannot access the context (RecipeContext) from the web project. If I try placing the validator class into the web app, I get an error that 'The Type or namespace name '
CategoryValidator' could not be found...'.

Here is CategoryValidator class

```
namespace Spicy.Entities.Validators
{
    public class CategoryValidator : AbstractValidator<Category>
    {
        public CategoryValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Category Name is required.").Must(UniqueName).WithMessage("This category name already exists.");
        }

        private bool UniqueName(Category category, string name)
        {
            using (RecipeContext db = new RecipeContext())
            {
                var dbCategory = db.Categories
                                .Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower())
                                .SingleOrDefault();

                if (dbCategory == null)
                    return true;

                return dbCategory.ID == category.ID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Category Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Spicy.Entities
{
    [Validator(typeof(CategoryValidator))]
    public class Category
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Category cannot be longer than 20 characters")]
        [Required]

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "User Name cannot be longer than 20 characters")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the global.asax code

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
    }
}
```

Where should I put the validator class and how do I get around the issues I'm having?

help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Simple solution (not best):
   Inject RecipeContext in your validator, place in Web

   - YourCompany.Domain

     - Models

       - Category
       - Other domain classes
   - YourCompany.Web

     - DataAccess

       - RecipeContext
     - Validators

       - CategoryValidator
       - other validators
     - Controllers

Code:

```
public class CategoryValidator : AbstractValidator<Category>
{
    RecipeContext _db;
    public CategoryValidator(RecipeContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Category Name is required.").Must(UniqueName).WithMessage("This category name already exists.");
    }

}
```

2. Advanced solution aligned with DDD:

   - YourCompany.Domain (no dependency on db or web)

     - Models

       - Category
       - Other domain classes
     - DataAccess

       - ICategoryRepository (works only with domain objects)
       - other repositories
     - Validators (for simplicity in domain but can be in YourCompany.Domain.Validators because depends on FluentValidation)

       - CategoryValidator (depends only on domain objects and domain services: for example ICategoryRepository)
   - YourCompany.DataAccess.EF

     - CategoryRepositoryEF  (implements ICategoryRepository with EF)
   - YourCompany.DataAccess.MongoDB (for example)

     - CategoryRepositoryMongo   (implements ICategoryRepository with MongoDB)
   - YourCompany.Web

     - Controllers
     - Startup

Code in Domain:

```
public interface ICategoryRepository
{
    bool ContainsCategory(string name);
    Category GetById(int id);
    // other db methods for example
    IEnumerable<Category> GetAll();
    void Add(Category entity);
}

public class CategoryValidator : AbstractValidator<Category>
{
    ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
    public CategoryValidator(ICategoryRepository categoryRepository)
    {
        _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().WithMessage("Category Name is required.").Must(UniqueName).WithMessage("This category name already exists.");
    }

    private bool UniqueName(Category category, string name)
    {
        return !_categoryRepository.Contains(name);
    }
}
```

Code in YourCompany.DataAccess.EF:

```
public class CategoryRepositoryEF
{
    RecipeContext _db;

    public CategoryRepository(RecipeContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    bool ContainsCategory(string name)
    {
        using (RecipeContext db = new RecipeContext())
        {
            var dbCategory = db.Categories
                            .Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == name.ToLower())
                            .SingleOrDefault();

            if (dbCategory == null)
                return true;

            return dbCategory.ID == category.ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Code in Web:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<RecipeContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    // Register application services.
    services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepositoryEF>();

}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. When I use your first solution and place the validator into the web project, I still get 'The Type or namespace name ' CategoryValidator' could not be found... in the model project'. Is there a way around this? Also, can you tell me the disadvantages to the first option? You mention it is not the 'best'.

Comment: You need to remove validation attribute and register validators in web startup: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/i.-ASP.NET-Core-integration

Comment: I noticed the link takes me to the 'Core' implementation. I am using MVC 5, not core. For simple MVC 5, I have placed the configuration in Global.Asax as JSkinner instructs. Thoughts?"

Comment: Forgive my lack of clarity, I am using ASP.Net, not ASP.Net Core.

Comment: Other sample is here. https://github.com/micro-elements/MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation.WebApi

Comment: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/h.-ASP.NET-MVC-5-integration

Comment: Following your second link above, I had followed JSkinner's instructions and I provided the Global.asax code above in my original question.

Comment: The other sample you mentioned "micro-elements" is for Web API, with an additional link to ASP.net Core. I am using MVC. I appreciate your help. Still trying to get this working.

Comment: from official docs:
Instead of using an attribute, you can also use a *custom validator factory* with an IoC container. You can tell the FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider to use a different validator factory by passing a nested closure into the Configure method which allows the provider to be customized:

    FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider => {
      provider.ValidatorFactory = new MyCustomValidatorFactory();
    })

Comment: I am unclear how this helps. In what way does the validator factory differ? I still may not be able to reach it from the model class project.